# Displaying records that contain a certain letter in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL table called `Customer` containing a column called `customer_country`. I would like to display all the countries that contain the letter `u`.

How would I do this? Im guessing its along the lines of

```
  select customer_country
  from Customer;
```

and using a like statement perhaps?
Regards

Comment: yes, it is along those lines

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I appreciate the response Andy, I had tried variations of things but it was hard to know if I was right or wrong, thats why I felt explaining what my lines of thought were was better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select customer_country 
from Customer 
where customer_country like '%u%'
```